# The Dice Star Strikes Back

Tags: visual, knowledge, crossword-clues

This puzzle is based on another one: called [A star made of dice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44171/a-star-made-of-dice) from a popular Italian puzzle maker @Alenanno (Who also helped me with this one). However there have been some modifications to make this puzzle more differenter.

**Instructions:**

1. A word of 6 letters has been engraved on each die. Definitions at the bottom must be solved to find these words.
2. Definitions are not given in the standard order (1,2,3,...), so you might have to properly associate each one (along with the solution) to its die. Observational skills are going to be your best weapon.
3. Letters on the dice are either **hidden** or **shown**. **Shown** letters should be removed from the clue word, therefore the remaining **hidden** letters will be used to progress in the puzzle.
4. When all the clue words have been found and placed, the hidden letters will give another question, following the numbers, and resulting in your final solution.
5. A complete answer would show: **(a)** all the clue words associated with their die number and definition (or just write them in order like a list), **(b)** the hidden definition, **(c)** the final word, and optionally, **(d)** hidden letters written in a sequence as a recap somewhere in the answer.

   **A note on formatting.** I'd like to request something for consistency across answers: as shown in the example below, hidden letters should be enclosed in `<sub>  </sub>` to increase readability (bold lettering is hardly visible). In case of multiple eligible letters, you may highlight any, as this is not relevant to finding the solution, i.e. `CARPAL` could be CAR<sub>PAL</sub> or C<sub>A</sub>R<sub>P</sub>A<sub>L</sub>.
   Therefore, an example answer could be:

   > Alpine ...
   >
   > PAL, IEN, ...
   >
   > ---
   >
   > 1. CAR<sub>P</sub><sub>AL</sub> - *definition here...*
   > 2. H<sub>I</sub>DD<sub>EN</sub> - *another definition here...*
   > 3. ...

   Again, apart from the single request I've made, any formatting choice is up to you.
6. You may safely ignore the inscription written around the center when solving the puzzle (while still appreciating the many years of experience of the author).

---

## Puzzle

[image: The dice star, preparing to destroy the Ivory moon of Gammon II]

### Definitions

> You, turned to meat. — Ones who cut stone. — Those who eat. — A maiden quite fat. — Remove mammalian garden pests. — Formed of natural fiber — Hopefully you, by a ruby kipper. — Foliage under the weather — Moved sneakily. — People Who Found Jenny's number.  — A bowdlerized British bird... according to a deal-making snake — First Generation water-related pocket monster — What a puzzle solver does, given incomplete information. — Made up for. — An arcade fighter. — Missing to an abnormal degree, esp. Scandinavian glacial erosion patterns. — Odes of praise. — Protect from harm.

---

In the interests of helping the visually impaired, the following description is provided: There are 18 dice, numbered, and laid out in a clockwise circle around a central die and inscription crediting @Alenanno. The Dice are labeled as follows, with the first letter being the up-face, and the following two being the other visible faces, read left-to-right.

> $1$. LED, $2$. IEE, $3$. TEA, $4$. KEN, $5$. KEN, $6$. LID, $7$. SER, $8$. TUT, $9$. LID, $10$. SAP, $11$. TUT, $12$. LID, $13$. SAP, $14$. PNG, $15$. SER, $16$. SER, $17$. TEA, $18$. LED

Comment: a 'ruby kipper' is probably a red herring, but I'm not sure what word this leads to

Comment: So I'm still wracking my brain on this... Any possibility of a hint? Or maybe let us know what ones we have that are right?

Comment: @PartyHatPanda Updated some clues this morning, sorry I was travelling for a few days with limited access. As you may guess, every updated clue had wrong (or no) answers, but not every unupdated clue had correct answers.

Comment: Is 'more differenter' a mistake, intentional or a hint?

Comment: @boboquack It was intentional as an informal, humorous, idiomatic way of saying "slightly different", It wasn't exactly intended as a hint, but since several of the clues are idiomatic, informal, and/or humorous it could easily be considered one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The final "question" is:

> WITH FRONDS LIKE THESE WHO NEEDS ANEMONES MARLIN IN FINDING NEMO

so I guess unlike the earlier Dice Star puzzle we aren't supposed to *answer* that question.

> I haven't watched the movie in ages but I think Marlin tries to tell this joke multiple times in the movie but fails for one reason or another until near the end. Something like that.

So, the words and "residual" letters in order of use are:

> `WIT` h `WILTED` Foliage under the weather [used to be: rough-looking foliage]
>  `HFR` d `HEIFER` A maiden quite fat
>  `OND` n `ATONED` Made up for
>  `SLI` f `SILKEN` Formed of natural fiber
>  `KET` o `TEKKEN` An arcade fighter
>  `HES` r `SHIELD` Protect from harm
>  `EWH` b `HEWERS` Ones who cut stone
>  `ONE` j `TUTONE` People who found Jenny's number
>  `EDS` i `SIDLED` Moved sneakily
>  `ANE` q `PAEANS` Odes of praise
>  `MON` a `MUTTON` You, turned to meat
>  `ESM` g `MISLED` Hopefully you, by a ruby kipper
>  `ARL` l `LAPRAS` First Generation water-related pocket monster
>  `INI` p `PINING` Missing to an abnormal degree, esp. Scandinavian glacial erosion patterns
>  `NFI` m `INFERS` What a puzzle solver does with incomplete information
>  `NDI` c `DINERS` Those who eat
>  `NGN` k `GANNET` A bowdlerized British bird... according to a deal-making snake
>  `EMO` e `DEMOLE` Remove mammalian garden pests

For the avoidance of doubt, I didn't find these all alone. I think I was the first to find these:

> SILKEN, TUTONE, GANNET, INFERS, PINING

and also independently found these (though others may well have found them too):

> DINERS, MISLED, ATONED, PAEANS, SHIELD

and I'm pretty certain I got these from other people either here or in Sphinx's Lair chat (most of them I either wouldn't in a million years have thought of or didn't believe when other people proposed them):

> MUTTON (Neon612), HEWERS (dcfyj), HEIFER (Neon612), DEMOLE (Rubio), WILTED (Rubio), SIDLED (MOehm), LAPRAS (ffao), TEKKEN (Sid).

The piecing-together, though, was all me :-).

Answer (score 7):

**Dice Update**

LED: Good

IEE: Good

TEA: Missing one

KEN: Good

LID: Good

SER: Good

TUT: Good

SAP: Missing One

PNG: Missing One

**PARTIAL ANSWER**

Moved sneakily(Correction from @MOehm)

> sIDLed-(LID from 3 and 17)

Found Jenny's number.(By Gareth)

> TUTone (TUT)

An arcade fighter.

> TekKEN (KEN)

First Generation water-related pocket monster

> hoRSEa (SER)

Protect from harm

> ShIeLD (LID)

Made up for

> ATonEd? (Not too sure about this) (TEA)

You, turned to meat (From Neon 612)

> mUTTon (TUT)

Formed of natural fibres (From Gareth)

> SilKEN (KEN)

Odes of praise(As Found by Michael Seifert)

> PAeanS (PAS)

Ones who cut stones(Modified by @Rubio)

> tilERS (SER)

Hopefully,you by a ruby kipper (by @PartyHatPanda)

> mIsLeD (LED)

Those who eat (Deusovi in the Sphinx Lair and Rubio here)

> dinERS

Remove garden pests (by @Rubio)

> DEmoLe (Not in OED as Gareth points out) (LED from 1 and 18)

A maiden quite fat. (@Neon612)

> HEIfEr (IEE)

Foliage under the weather (@Rubio)

> wILteD (LID)

A bowdlerized British bird... according to a deal-making snake (Gareth and Rubio)

> gAnnEt (TEA)

What a puzzle solver does, given incomplete information. (Gareth)

> infSER (SER)

Missing to an abnormal degree, esp. Scandinavian glacial erosion patterns (From Rubio)

> PiniNG (PNG)

Comment: I think atoned is probably right

Comment: I'm not sure that your answer for _Ones who cut stones_ is correct - it is specific to [wood](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sawyer). That being said, I have no clue what else it could be as I have been wracking my head on it since I saw the puzzle.

Comment: I doubt sawyer, too; apart from referring to someone who saws timber, the clue seems to require a plural. (Unfortunately, masons doesn't match any dice.) And I think moved sneakily is sidled rather than patter; it fits both the form and the kind of movement better

Comment: @MOehm Check the latest edit.

Comment: @Sid would it make sense to edit in the rest of the clues, but just leave them blank? It seems like we are all jumping in to your answer as a full submission, and it might be helpful to see what has already been answered and what still needs to be all in one spot.

Comment: @PartyHatPanda Mutton has TUT

Comment: @Sid yes but that's the only one that does and there are two dice with TUT. Unless I missed one.

Comment: Ah, Yes, I missed the 2nd TUT... Apologies

Comment: with the updated definitions, Remove mammalian garden pests would then most likely be DEmoLe - same LED from 1/18.

Comment: Deal making snake sounds like Satan, not sure how it would relate to birds though

Comment: PINING is from Gareth in Sphinx Lair

Answer (score 6):

I currently have a full set of answers to all clues that fit all dice.  I have no idea if they are *correct* - that's all going to depend on if the hidden letters add up to a usable clue.

But here's what I have, in the interest of giving back to the people who contributed so many responses already:

> ```
> heifer  IEE     A maiden quite fat.             (dubious.)
> tekken  KEN     An arcade fighter.
> silken  KEN     Formed of natural fiber
> demole  LED     Remove mammalian garden pests.
> misled  LED,LID Hopefully you, by a ruby kipper.
> sidled  LED,LID Moved sneakily.
> shield  LED,LID Protect from harm.              (shield, secure)
> wilted  LED,LID Foliage under the weather.      (dubious.)
> pining  PNG     Missing to an abnormal degree, esp. Scandinavian glacial erosion patterns. (@Gareth)
> paeans  SAP     Odes of praise. 
> lapras  SAP     First Generation water-related pocket monster   (horsea, seadra, lapras)
> tilers  SER     Ones who cut stone.             (hewers, tilers)
> diners  SER     Those who eat.
> corpse  SER     You, turned to meat.            (mutton, corpse)
> atoned  TEA     Made up for. 
> gannet  TEA     A bowdlerized British bird... according to a deal-making snake @Gareth
> intuit  TUT     What a puzzle solver does, given incomplete information.
> tutone  TUT     People Who Found Jenny's number. (why not plural?)
> ```

entries that are my independent contributions (some may have been found in Sphinx Lair in parallel):

> ```
> demole  LED     Remove mammalian garden pests.
> wilted  LED,LID Foliage under the weather.      (dubious.)
> lapras  SAP     First Generation water-related pocket monster
> tilers  SER     Ones who cut stone.
> diners  SER     Those who eat.
> corpse  SER     You, turned to meat.
> intuit  TUT     What a puzzle solver does, given incomplete information.
> ```

since some words can be used on more than one die, this writeup doesn't use the HiDDen notation.  I have a completely speculative and quite certainly wrong set of word -> die assignments here as well, if that helps anyone:

> ```
>  1. LED         DEmoLe  demole
>  2. IEE         hEIfEr  heifer?
>  3. TEA         ATonEd  atoned
>  4. KEN         tekKEN  tekken
>  5. KEN         silKEN  silken
>  6. LID         shIeLD  shield
>  7. SER         dinERS  diners
>  8. TUT         TUTone  tutone
>  9. LID         sIDLed  sidled
> 10. SAP         PAeanS  paeans
> 11. TUT         inTUiT  intuit
> 12. LID         mIsLeD  misled
> 13. SAP         lAPraS  lapras
> 14. PNG         PiNinG  pining
> 15. SER         tilERS  tilers?
> 16. SER         coRpSE  corpse?
> 17. TEA         gAnnET  gannet
> 18. LED         wiLtED  wilted?
> ```

these are mostly literal dumps of my notes, so sorry for how they're formatted.

Answer (score 5):

**Partial Answer**

You, turned to meat

> mUTTon (TUT)

A maiden quite fat

> HEIfEr (IEE)

Comment: In regards to _Ones who cut stone_ I'm going to piggy-back from @Moehm above, the way the clue is phrased sounds like it should be plural. Plus, your answer is not specific to stone cutting.

Comment: @PartyHatPanda You're probably right. I was going for Stone Cutter but I think its too general.

Answer (score 5):

**Partial Answer**

Hopefully you, by a ruby kipper

> mIsLeD (ILD From 6,9,12)

A bowdlerized bird... according to a deal-making snake

> Maybe TUfTed? For Tufted Titmouse? It uses snake skin when making its nest... a weak connection but there isn't any other progress.

Rough looking foliage

> ASPera (ASP from 10, 13; or SER from 7, 16, 15), also known as the [rough rattlesnakeroot](http://plants.usda.gov/core/profile?symbol=PRAS)

Comment: Ice Age is very general. It might be [ELsTer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elster_glaciation), one of the glaciations in Northern Europe.

Comment: I was worried about that. But yours works really well! @Sid could probably add it, I think.

Comment: The OP probably hints at an old probability puzzle at the Sphinx Lair. But, he might well have been distracting me..

Comment: @Sid I was trying to find some reference to a deal making snake. Can you reference the puzzle?

Comment: I doubt, I can find one. Could take a wild guess like The monty-Hall's problem. But, I wouldn't count on it..

Comment: @Sid Monty Hall hosted *Lets Make a Deal*, and the snake could be a Python. So... Monty Python?

Comment: @Neon612 6-lettered word?

Comment: @Sid Working on it. I did manage to find [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Parrot_sketch). Not sure if It will help, though.

Answer (score 4):

**Partial answer:**

"Odes of praise" is possibly:

> PA<sub>EAN</sub>S (#10 & #13)

Comment: Yep, this could be right. Paeans make much more sense than What I had thought initially

Answer (score 3):

Found Jenny's number

> DIaLed from #6, 9 or 12 or DiaLEd from #1 or 18

First Generation Water-related pocket monster

> hoRSEa from #7, 15 or 16

What a puzzle solver does

> anSwER from #7, 15 or 16

Protect from harm (from @Sid's answer)

> shIeLD from #6, 9, or 12